# Detect if Radiance or Ambiance is the current look

Tags: settings, dconf

To interactively change icon colors, I want my program to be able to detect whether Ambiance or Radiance is the current looks. 
I found this  value to be stored in dconf-editor under org->gnome->desktop->interface->gtk-theme.

Where is the file from which my program can read this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a python version as it sounds like that's what you're working with:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gi.repository import Gio

SCHEMA = 'org.gnome.desktop.interface'
KEY = 'gtk-theme'

gsettings = Gio.Settings.new(SCHEMA)
print(gsettings.get_string(KEY))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read information with the dconf command. For example...

```
$ dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/interface/gtk-theme
'Adwaita'
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this the same in python syntax? I write my program in a python script.

Comment: I'd use the subprocess module. For all options see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python